# how to call action from href link mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I have this:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
 <li><a href="doctors.html">All Hospital</a> </li>
 <li><a href="@Html.ActionLink("AddHospital","AddHospital","Home")">Add Hospital</a> </li>
<li><a href="edit-doctor.html">Edit Hospital</a> </li>
 </ul>
```

when i click `AddHospital` button the page will redirect to `AddHospital` . But i getting one error The resource cannot be found.below i attached images

[image: See my pic]

[image: Error]

Comment: Its `@Html.ActionLink("Add Hospital","AddHospital","Home")` - not wrapped inside a `<a>` tag - of if you do want to generate it manually, then its `<a href="@Url.Action("AddHospital", "Home")">Add Hospital</a>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks it's working fine

Answer (score 1):

Hope ,Below information will be helpful for you:

What is  UrlHelper.Action Method

As per MSDN,Its Generates a fully qualified URL to an action method.

**ex:**

@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { id = 54, com = "delete", page = "5" })

In the above example,the first parameter is the name of the action method and the second parameter is the name of the controller in which this action method exists. And finally the third paramater is the object parameter that is used to pass the parameter to the action method of the controller.

**Difference between UrlHelper.action and Html.ActionLink method?**

Html.ActionLink generates an  tag whereas Url.Action returns only an url.

For example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("link text", "someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123" }, null)
```

generates:

```
<a href="/somecontroller/someaction/123">link text</a>
```

and

```
Url.Action("someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123" })
```

generates:

```
/somecontroller/someaction/123
```

Thanks

Karthik